# javascript regex validation

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there any way to find which input character fails the **regex pattern**.

For ex: consider [A-Za-z\s.&] is only allowable but the user enter like "test/string" where '/' invalidates input. *How to find who fails regex **(our case '/')***

Comment: all answers are good. RoToRa perfectly matches my need. thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the valid chars and you'll have a string of the invalid ones:

```
var invalid = "test/string".replace(/[A-Za-z\s.&]/g,""); // results in "/"
```

Answer (score 1):

To find which characters fails, split it with `/[A-Za-z\s.&]+/`, you will get invalid characters list

```
"test/string".split(/[A-Za-z\s.&]+/).join('')
/
```

To check username is valid or not, you could just use ^ and $ anchors.

```
/^[A-Za-z\s.&]+$/
```

Comment: I think he's got that part covered, but he wants to find out *why* the match failed, i. e. on which character.

Answer (score 1):

Just negate your character class and find out which character(s) match.

```
[^A-Za-z\s.&]
```

will match the `/` in `test/string`. So, altogether you get

```
if (/^[A-Za-z\s.&]+$/.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    result = subject.match(/[^A-Za-z\s.&]/g);
    // result is an array that contains all the characters that failed the match
}
```